# Help with simple update case trigger

Tags: trigger

I'm declarative developer trying to make this work:
I am trying to update the case owner to a queuename based on status.  Here is my code and the error I'm getting below.  Any help would be appreciated!

```
    trigger CRME_Case_ReOpen_OOO on Case (before update) {            
        for(case c :trigger.new){       

          if(c.OwnerOOO__c == TRUE &&  c.Status == 'Working' ) 

                c.OwnerID =  [select Id from User where Name = :c.QueueNameRef__c].Id;              
                }                                    
   }
```

Error:Apex trigger CRME_Case_ReOpen_OOO caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: CRME_Case_ReOpen_OOO: execution of BeforeUpdate caused by: System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject: Trigger.CRME_Case_ReOpen_OOO: line 14, column 1

Comment: Can we see your test class?

Comment: @user8129 This task can be accomplished with a workflow rule and a field update action. Is there an unsaid reason you're doing this with a trigger?

Comment: your query isnt returning any records

Comment: Your query doesn't doesn't appear to bring back any results.  Is that field properly filled out?  BTW, you never want to do a query inside a loop anyways.  You should query for it outside the loop and assign via a map.

Comment: @user8129 I tried an Workflow, but Field Updates doesn't allow owners to be updated from a variable, so I'd need to code for owner as a variable which I have stored in c.QueueNameRef.  Or is there a way I can do it?

Comment: @dphil - how do I do a map?  Maybe I can add a debug statement right after I do that..?

Comment: @MarkPond - I tried an Workflow, but Field Updates doesn't allow owners to be updated from a variable, so I'd need to code for owner as a variable which I have stored in c.QueueNameRef. Or is there a way I can do it? –

Comment: @user8129 for each of the values that are possible in the `QueueNameRef__c` field, you would have one workflow rule and one corresponding field update action to set the owner to the appropriate Queue. If there are just a couple of possible values for this field and the 'rules' change infrequently, this might be a manageable approach.

Comment: Looks like Keith gave u an example that uses a map.  It appears like it should work.

Answer (score 4):

In case you can't find a workflow solution...

This is a more defensive version of the trigger that also avoids the query inside a loop problem (that can cause the 100 SOQL queries governor limit to be exceeded). But as the comments mention, if there are inconsistent data values they also need fixing.

```
trigger CRME_Case_ReOpen_OOO on Case (before update) {  
    Set<String> names = new Set<String>();          
    for (Case c : Trigger.new) {       
        if (c.OwnerOOO__c && c.Status == 'Working' && c.QueueNameRef__c != null) {
            names.add(c.QueueNameRef__c);
        }
    }
    if (names.size() > 0) {
        Map<String, Id> m = new Map<String, Id>();
        for (User u : [
                select Id, Name
                from User
                where Name in :names
                order by Name
                ]) {
            m.put(u.Name, u.Id);
        }
        for (Case c : Trigger.new) {       
            if (c.OwnerOOO__c && c.Status == 'Working' && c.QueueNameRef__c != null) {
                Id id = m.get(c.QueueNameRef__c);
                if (id != null) {
                    c.OwnerID = id;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Keith.... I just copy/pasted your code unchanged and it's giving a compile error on this line:

Comment: if (names.length() > 0) {       Error: Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [SET<String>].length() at line 8 column 9

Comment: @user8129 Change it to names.size().

Comment: if (names.size()> 0) ... --but user8129 you should have been able to figure this out that Set collections support the size() method, not the length() method. I'm sure that Keith C, who is exceptionally helpful to 'thousands' just made a simple error while trying to help you expeditiously

Comment: @keithc  thanks to both.  The size made it save OK.  (remember I'm a declarative programmer :-(  don't know much.  I'll start testing and see how far I get.  Thanks to all again!